# Las etiquetas nav y articles, se salen de su contenedor padre

Tags: css, css3

Esperando que se encuentren bien, espero que me ayuden con el siguiente problema:

Estoy practicando `flexbox` y estaba realizando el modelo que les voy a dejar con el código mas abajo, el problema es que cuando le agrego a las etiquetas `nav` y `article` un `margin`, estos dos se salen de su contenedor padre hacia afuera, pero si les saco el `margin` vuelven a la normalidad.

Tengo entendido que esto se llama **colapso de margenes** y la verdad es que he intentado solucionarlo pero no lo he podido hacer, espero que me ayuden, gracias! .

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.box{
    background: salmon;
    width: 80%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-elements{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-container{
    background: cyan;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header{
    background: red;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 35px
}

.aside{
    background: green;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}

.nav{
    background: blue;
    width: 70%; 
    margin: 10px;
}

.article{
    background: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 70%;
}

.footer{
    background: violet;
    height: 10%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
        <header class="header flex-elements">Header</header>
        <main class="main-container">
            <aside class="flex-elements aside">Aside</aside>
            <nav class="flex-elements nav">Nav</nav>
            <article class="flex-elements article">Article</article>
        </main>
        <footer class="flex-elements footer">Footer</footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema viene de que la suma de tu `<aside>` + `<nav>` o la de `<aside>` + `<article>` suman el **100%** de su padre, (30% + 70%) por lo que al darle el `margin: 10px` estás provocando que se pase y se comporte de la manera que muestras (30% + 70% + 20px + 20px = 100% + 40px que coincide con los 40 píxeles que rebasan tus elementos de su contenedor).

Una manera para controlar eso es usar la función `calc` para contemplar ese espacio de más en el tamaño del elemento.

Ejemplo:

```
.aside{
    background: green;
    width: calc(30% - 20px); /*Por el margin: 10px que dará 10 a la izquierda y 10 a la derecha*/
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Te dejó como se comportaría en tu código:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.box{
    background: salmon;
    width: 80%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-elements{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-container{
    background: cyan;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header{
    background: red;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 35px
}

.aside{
    background: green;
    width: calc(30% - 20px);
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav{
    background: blue;
    width: calc(70% - 20px); 
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article{
    background: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(70% - 20px);
    border: 2px solid pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer{
    background: violet;
    height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <header class="header flex-elements">Header</header>
    <main class="main-container">
        <aside class="flex-elements aside">Aside</aside>
        <nav class="flex-elements nav">Nav</nav>
        <article class="flex-elements article">Article</article>
    </main>
    <footer class="flex-elements footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: ohhh de verdad muchas gracias, me ayudaste bastante, ahora si le quisiera agregar bordes, tambien tengo que agrgarlos al calc para que me haga el calculo correspondiente y funcionen verdad??

Comment: Si le dieses al `<aside>`, al `<article>` y al `<nav>` la propiedad `box-sizing: border-box;` harías que el borde no cuente para determinar el tamaño del elemento. De no usarlo si que tendrías que contemplar el `border` en la función `calc()`. Edité mi respuesta para que veas como se haría con `box-sizing`.

Comment: ohhh vale muchas gracias, me salvaste la vida de verdad!! :,)

Comment: Si te sirvió deja la respuesta como aceptada a ser posible ^^